# Template string not working with the link in AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to load statics of countries using [restcountries.eu](https://restcountries.eu/), with the help of AJAX. But when I use template string on the link e.g. `` xhttp.open('GET', `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}`, true) ``; It can't find the link and throws the error 400. And the error is this: `console: GET https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/ 400`. I wonder what's wrong?! I haven't seen anything like this before.

Wait 5secs until you can see the console error.

p.s. I'm a beginner to AJAX and I want to do it with XHR, anyway I know no one uses that. I can do it with *async / await*, but just for now, **XHR**.

```js
const countries = () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('#section--input');

  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open('GET', `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input.value}`, true);

  xhttp.onload = function() {

    if (this.status === 200) {
      const src = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      console.log(src.flag)
      console.log('Fetch API is working!');
    } else {
      console.log('Fetch API is not working!');
    }
  }

  xhttp.send();

  // Making sure the value is true
  console.log(input);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', countries);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Country" id="section--input">
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: `input` seems to be empty when the request is sent, according to the URL in your error.

Comment: You're also using `input` in your template string AND appending it afterwards. Once should be sufficient...

Comment: After testing I found that your code gives error `400` which means a bad request, looking back at your code I can see the issue: `\`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}\` + input` you are adding input twice to the URL do: `\`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing I found that your code gives error `400` which means a `bad request`, looking back at your code I can see the issue: `\`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}` + input`you are adding input twice to the URL do:``https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}``

```js
const countries = () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('#section--input').value;

  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.open('GET', `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${input}`, true);

  xhttp.onload = function() {

    if (this.status === 200) {
      const src = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      console.log(src.flag)
      console.log('Fetch API is working!');
    } else {
      console.log('Fetch API is not working!');
    }
  }

  xhttp.send();

  // Making sure the value is true
  console.log(input);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', countries);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a mistake only in stackoverflow, my main code doesn't contain this. However, I changed some in my code also and now is working.

Comment: I wonder how that's actually fixing the issue, as the error message in the OP clearly shows that the URL doesn't include anything after `alpha`.